# Error when trying to get firebase data throught http get

Tags: typescript, http, google-cloud-firestore, get, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to get my firestore data through HTTP get request, but I'm receiving this error when attempting. I think it would be easier if my data in firestore was in JSON format. I don't know if it is possible to set so.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /api/v1/getsensor/0/led1</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

This is my firestore get code:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as firebaseHelper from 'firebase-functions-helper/dist';
import * as express from 'express';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore();
db.settings({timestampInSnapshots: true});

const app = express();
const main = express();

main.use(bodyParser.json());
main.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
main.use('/api/v1', app);

const sensorCollection = 'dadosusuarios';
export const webApi = functions.https.onRequest(main);

app.patch('/sensor/:sensorId', async(req, res) => {
try{
    await firebaseHelper.firestore.updateDocument(db, sensorCollection, req.params.sensorId, 
req.body);
    res.status(200).send("Update Success");
}catch (error){
    res.status(204).send("Patch Error");
}
});

app.get('/getsensor', async(req, res) =>{
try{
    await firebaseHelper.firestore.getDocument(db, sensorCollection, req.params.sensorId).then(doc => 
console.log('data'));
    res.status(200).send("Get Success");
}catch (error){
    res.status(204).send("Get Error");
}
});
```

This is how I tried accesing the data, I used postman to make the test:

```
https://home-automation-6ed64.web.app/api/v1/getsensor/mydocid/led1
```

This is an image of my firestore:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best and easier way for you to achieve this, it's by using Firestore API to retrieve values. This way, you will be able to easily access your data and return the values in a JSON format, as you want to.

For you to achieve that, you need to follow a pattern of URL to retrieve the values. An example is the below URL:

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/databases/(default)/documents/dadosusuarios/<usuario>
```

More information you can find in the official documentation here: [Making Rest Calls](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api#making_rest_calls)

However, in case you need to use the `Express` methods that you are using, you can check this documentation for more information: [Call functions via HTTP requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events)

And I would start by adding this below part to your code, so the authentication and CORS problem are not affecting you.

```
// Automatically allow cross-origin requests
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));

// Add middleware to authenticate requests
app.use(myMiddleware);
```

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Where should I add this HTTP API request that you have inserted in the start?

Comment: Hi @NiltonSchumacherF it seems that the URL that you are using to perform the call in the Postman is not correct. This way, it's not being able to access the information. The part `Cannot GET /api/v1/getsensor/0/led1` in the error indicates that. You should use the URL as indicated in this documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api#making_rest_calls), as the way you were trying to use your URL to make the call.